# Function to remove elements from array

Tags: c, arrays

Given an array, I have to find the minimum element, remove all the elements equal to minimum, then subtract the minimum to all values different to minimum. Repeat until only 1 element is left.

Example:
starting point{5,4,4,2,2,8} 6 elements

{3,2,2,6} 4 elements

{1,4} 2 elements

{3} 1 elements

Output must be a new array like this {6,4,2,1}

My functions:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int currentsize;

int findmin(int size,int* lengths){
    int i;
    int min=lengths[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(lengths[i]<min){
            min=lengths[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

void removemin(int size,int* lengths,int min){
    int i,j,min_count,newlength;
    min_count=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(lengths[i]==min){
            min_count++;
        }
    }
    newlength=size-min_count;
    int supp[newlength];
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(lengths[i]!=min){
            supp[j]=lengths[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<newlength;i++){
        lengths[i]=supp[i]-min;
    }
    currentsize=newlength;

}
```

output function I'm working on

```
int* solution(int lengths_count, int* lengths, int* result_count) {
    int i,j,min,bamboo_pieces;
    int supp[1000];
    supp[0]=lengths_count;
    *(result_count)=1;
    i=1;
    while(lengths_count>1){
        min=findmin(lengths_count,lengths);
        removemin(lengths_count,lengths,min);
        lengths_count=currentsize;
        supp[i]=currentsize;
        i++;
        *(result_count)++;
    }
    int *result;
    result=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*(result_count)));
    for(j=1;j<*(result_count);j++){
        supp[j]=result[j];
    }
    return result;

}
```

Main function to read input. I changed it a bit so there is no need to scan any input:

```
int main(){
   int n=6;
   int i;
   int *lengths;
   lengths=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
   lengths[0]=5;
   lengths[1]=4;
   lengths[2]=4;
   lengths[3]=2;
   lengths[4]=2;
   lengths[5]=8;
   int x=0;
   int *result_count;
   result_count=&x;
   int *myoutput=solution(n,lengths,result_count);
   for(i=0;i<*(result_count);i++){
       printf("%d",*(myoutput+i));
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I'm stuck and can't find what I'm doing wrong, tried to follow the logic step by step but it's not working. Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: You initialized element 2 twice.....

Comment: Did you try with debugger ? With debugger, you can figure out what exact step failed in your code

Comment: Simpler to just subtract the second-highest element from the highest and return that.

Comment: @Mizzet The name  lengths declared like int* lengths and the name  newlength declared like int newlength make the code unclear.

Comment: You are,passing in result_count while uninitialized and then dereferencing it - UB.

Comment: You return a mallocated array pointer and then dump it - leak.

Comment: Please expand on 'not working'....

Comment: @Martin James I'm getting Segmentation fault error

Comment: `result_count` is not allocated

Comment: Ok, sounds about right.  Fix above and test again.

Comment: @Martin James I noticed those mistakes I made when creating this post, I changed them now. Made a int pointer myoutput to store what's returned from output function. Still getting "Segmentation Fault, core cumped"